# Dexie eachUniqueKey and Where Clause

Tags: electron, indexeddb, quasar-framework, dexie

I'm developing an application in Quasar/Electron and using Dexie/IndexedDB for my database. I want to find all distinct records in the database that contain both my Event ID and a Dog ID (both key indexed fields).  I am able to do this with the following code:

```
await myDB.runTable
   .orderBy('[fk_event+fk_dog]')
   .eachUniqueKey((theDuo) => {
   this.runsArray.push({eventID: theDuo[0], dogID: theDuo[1]})
  })
```

I'm using a combined key which is working well.  However, I need to have more of the records than just the keys. I need a few more fields, is this possible?

I was trying to get records with the unique key function while also using the where function, but that doesn't seem to work.

I need to get all the unique (distinct?) dogs in the table that are in a particular event.  And also get their corresponding information. I'm not sure if there is a better, more efficient way to do this? I can always pull out all the records and loop through them to build a custom array, I was just hoping to do this at the table read level. (yeah I'm still in tables/records even though these are collections etc. :p ).

Even the above code gives me all the events, and I can pull out what I need with a filter.  I just was thinking it would be faster and more efficient to do it at the read level.

```
this.enteredRuns = this.runsArray.filter((theEvent) => {
    return ( (theEvent.eventID == this.currentEventID) )
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
await myDB.runTable
  .orderBy('[fk_event+fk_dog]')
  .clone({unique: "unique"})
  .toArray()
```

I know this isn't documented but it should do the work to use unique cursor while still extracting the whole objects and not just the keys. You cannot combine with `where` but you could use `.filter`. Just be aware that not all records with be scanned as it will jump over records with same keys - selecting the first visited records only.